# Eliminating volume envelope retrigger clicks - Jsyn on Android

Tags: android, audio, envelope, jsyn

I am looking for ideas on how to handle envelope re-triggering of new notes in a monophonic sampler setup causing clicks if the previous note's envelope hasn't finished. In the current setup the previous note's instance is killed on the spot when a new note is triggered (the synth.stop method call), causing a click as the envelope doesn't get a chance to finish and reach 0 volume. Any hints are welcome.

I have also added in the below code my own un-satisfactory solution putting the gain of the voice to 0 and then putting the voice to sleep for 70ms. This introduces a 70ms latency to the user interaction but gets rid of any clicks. Any values below 70ms in the sleep don't solve the clicking.

The variable are public static at the moment just so I can still play around with where I'm calling them.

Here is my listener code:

```
buttonNoteC1Get.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                buttonNoteC1Get.setBackgroundColor(myColorWhite); // reset gui color
                if (sample.getSustainBegin() > 0) { // trigger release for looping sample
                    ampEnv.dataQueue.queue(ampEnvelope, 3, 1); // release called
                }
                limit = 0; // reset action down limiter
                return true;
            }

            if (limit == 0) { // respond only to first touch event
                if (samplePlayer != null) { // check if a previous note exists
                    synth.stop(); // stop instance of previous note
                }
                buttonNoteC1Get.setBackgroundColor(myColorGrey); // key pressed gui color
                samplePitch = octave * 1; // set samplerate multiplier
                Sampler.player(); // call setup code for new note
                Sampler.play(); // play new note
                limit = 1; // prevent stacking of action down touch events
            }
            return false;
        }

    }); // end listener
```

Here is my Sampler code

```
public class Sampler {

public static VariableRateDataReader samplePlayer;
public static LineOut lineOut;
public static FloatSample sample;
public static SegmentedEnvelope ampEnvelope;
public static VariableRateMonoReader ampEnv;
public static MixerMonoRamped mixerMono;
public static double[] ampData;
public static FilterStateVariable mMainFilter;

public static Synthesizer synth = JSyn.createSynthesizer(new JSynAndroidAudioDevice());

// load the chosen sample, called by instrument select spinner
static void loadSample(){
    SampleLoader.setJavaSoundPreferred(false);
    try {
        sample = SampleLoader.loadFloatSample(sampleFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} // end load sample


// initialize sampler voice
static void player() {

 // Create an amplitude envelope and fill it with data.
 ampData = new double[] {
         envA, 0.9, //  pair 0, "attack"
         envD, envS, // pair 2, "decay"
         0, envS, // pair 3, "sustain"
         envR, 0.0, // pair 4, "release"
        /* 0.04, 0.0 // pair 5, "silence"*/

 };

    // initialize voice
    ampEnvelope = new SegmentedEnvelope(ampData);
    synth.add(ampEnv = new VariableRateMonoReader());
    synth.add(lineOut = new LineOut());
    synth.add(mixerMono = new MixerMonoRamped(2));
    synth.add(mMainFilter = new FilterStateVariable());

    // connect signal flow
    mixerMono.output.connect(mMainFilter.input);
    mMainFilter.output.connect(0, lineOut.input, 0);
    mMainFilter.output.connect(0, lineOut.input, 1);

    // set control values
    mixerMono.amplitude.set(sliderVal / 100.0f);
    mMainFilter.amplitude.set(0.9);
    mMainFilter.frequency.set(mainFilterCutFloat);
    mMainFilter.resonance.set(mainFilterResFloat);

    // initialize and connect sampler voice
 if (sample.getChannelsPerFrame() == 1) {
     synth.add(samplePlayer = new VariableRateMonoReader());
     ampEnv.output.connect(samplePlayer.amplitude);
     samplePlayer.output.connect(0, mixerMono.input, 0);
     samplePlayer.output.connect(0, mixerMono.input, 1);
 } else if (sample.getChannelsPerFrame() == 2) {
     synth.add(samplePlayer = new VariableRateStereoReader());
     ampEnv.output.connect(samplePlayer.amplitude);
     samplePlayer.output.connect(0, mixerMono.input, 0);
     samplePlayer.output.connect(1, mixerMono.input, 1);
 } else {
     throw new RuntimeException("Can only play mono or stereo samples.");
 }

} // end player

// play the sample
public static void play() {

    if (samplePlayer != null)
    {samplePlayer.dataQueue.clear();
        samplePlayer.rate.set(sample.getFrameRate() * samplePitch); // set pitch
    }

    // start the synth engine
    synth.start();
    lineOut.start();
    ampEnv.start();

   // play one shot sample
    if (sample.getSustainBegin() < 0) {
        samplePlayer.dataQueue.queue(sample);
        ampEnv.dataQueue.queue( ampEnvelope );

    // play sustaining sample
    } else {
        samplePlayer.dataQueue.queueOn(sample);
        ampEnv.dataQueue.queue( ampEnvelope, 0,3);
        ampEnv.dataQueue.queueLoop( ampEnvelope, 1, 2 );
    }
} }
```

Unsatisfactory solution that introduces 70ms of latency, changing the action down listener handling of a previous note to this:

```
 if (limit == 0) {
                if (samplePlayer != null) {
                    mixerMono.amplitude.set(0);
                    try {
                        synth.sleepFor(0.07);
                        synth.stop(); // stop instance of previous note
                    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not call synth.start() and synth.stop() for every note. Think of it like powering on a physical synthesizer. Just start the synth and the lineOut once. If the ampEnv is connected indirectly to something else that is start()ed then you do not need to start() the ampEnv.

Then just queue your samples and envelopes when you want to start a note.

When you are all done playing notes then call synth.stop().

Comment: ok yes i understand that, but still the envelope issue remains no?

Comment: Look at this example for crossfading samples.  https://github.com/philburk/jsyn/blob/master/tests/com/jsyn/examples/PlaySampleCrossfade.java,           
       look for the call to setCrossFadeIn().  That can be used to prevent samples from clicking when you queue one after another.. you don't need to do anything special for envelopes. they will automatically go from their current position and so generally they will not click.